# Binding arbitary depth tree to a TreeView

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, binding

I've got the following interface (as you can see, I'm adapting the MVVM pattern a bit):

```
public interface IViewModel {
    string Header { get; }
    IEnumerable<IViewModel> Nodes { get; }
}
```

I want to bind this datatype to a treeview, with a single top node and an arbitary depth. `Header` is the text to display in each node, and `Nodes` are the child nodes.

I've got the following XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:IViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

and setting the top-level node to the DataContext of the Window:

```
IViewModel model = ViewModelFactory.GetTopLevelViewModel();
DataContext = model;
```

However, nothing is appearing in the treeview. I've looked at quite a few similar questions on SO and elsewhere, but none seem to solve my problem. A few questions:

1. Why do I need to set the `DataContext` of the parent Window, and not the TreeView itself?
2. Why is nothing appearing in the treeview?
3. How do I fix it?

Comment: I think the hierarchacaldatatemplate will match the actual data type and not the interface type, I may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do I need to set the DataContext
>   of the parent Window, and not the
>   TreeView itself?

You don't need to. You can set the data context on the `TreeView` itself:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tree"...>
```

-

```
IViewModel model = ViewModelFactory.GetTopLevelViewModel();
tree.DataContext = model;
```

> Why is nothing appearing in the
>   treeview?

`TreeView` is an `ItemsControl`. In order to make it display something you need to assign its `ItemsSource` property to a **collection**.

> How do I fix it?

For example, you can set the `DataContext` to a collection of `IViewModel` items instead of a single item:

```
IViewModel model = ViewModelFactory.GetTopLevelViewModel();
tree.DataContext = new IViewModel[] { model };
```